# Simulating multi-wheel vehicles in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'm quite new with Gazebo and URDF. I followed the tutorials provided by the wiki, but I still have some questions. My objective is to model a vehicle in Gazebo with an arbitrary number of wheels, which have 2 degrees of freedom (translation and rotation). I know how to do that part using URDF. However, I don't know how I can control those wheels independently. I want to have a ROS node where I can set the translation speed and the orientation angle of each wheel independently. Is that possible? Can anybody give me a hint about it?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9256/simulating-multi-wheel-vehicles-in-gazebo/) by [gazkune](https://answers.ros.org/users/165/gazkune/) on ROS Answers with karma: 219 on 2011-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As suggested by David, writing a ros plugin similar to [diffdrive plugin](http://ua-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/stacks/erratic_robot/trunk/erratic_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin.cpp) used in erratic model is probably the easiest way.

Alternatively, if for some reason you are familiar with the [pr2 mechanism stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism) and wanted to use the [pr2 controllers stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_controllers), you can see the [single_link.launch](https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/pr2_simulator/trunk/pr2_examples_gazebo/single_link.launch) example in [pr2_examples_gazebo package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_examples_gazebo) as a starting point.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1